# Based on the Andreotti-Frankel theorem, what is the CW complex homotopy equivalent to $x^2 + y^2 - 1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry

I am referring to this theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreotti%E2%80%93Frankel_theorem

I have no idea how to begin thinking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-singular conic is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. The underlying topological space is just a 2-sphere.

Comment: The theorem appears to be about affine varieties, not projective varieties, in which case we're talking about $\mathbb{P}^1$ with (in this case) two points removed, which is homotopy equivalent to a circle. (For that matter a 2-sphere is not real dimension 1, which is what the theorem is supposed to provide.)

Comment: You are right !